# Estimate the Kullback-Leibler divergence

Tags: kullback-leibler

I would like to be sure I am able to compute the KL divergence based on a sample.

Assume the data come from a Gamma distribution with shape=1/.85 and scale=.85.

> set.seed(937)
>
> theta <- .85
>
> x <- rgamma(1000, shape=1/theta, scale=theta)

Based on that sample, I would like to compute the KL-divergence from the real underlying distribution to an inverse gaussian distribution with mean 1 (mu=1) and precision 0.832 (lambda=0.832).

I obtain KL = 1.286916.

Can you confirm I compute it well?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Mathematica,* using *symbolic* integration (not an approximation!), reports a value that equals 1.6534640367102553437 to 20 decimal digits.

```
red = GammaDistribution[20/17, 17/20];
gray = InverseGaussianDistribution[1, 832/1000];
kl[pF_, qF_] := Module[{p, q},
   p[x_] := PDF[pF, x];
   q[x_] := PDF[qF, x];
   Integrate[p[x] (Log[p[x]] - Log[q[x]]), {x, 0, \[Infinity]}]
   ];
kl[red, gray]
```

In general, using a small Monte-Carlo sample is inadequate for computing these integrals.  As we saw in [another thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/6814/919), the value of the KL divergence can be dominated by the integral in short intervals where the base PDF is nonzero and the other PDF is close to zero.  A small sample can miss such intervals entirely and it can take a large sample to hit them enough times to obtain an accurate result.

Take a look at the Gamma PDF (red, dashed) and the log PDF (gray) for the Inverse Gaussian near 0:

[image: Gamma pdf]

[image: Log of Inverse Gamma pdf]

In this case, the Gamma PDF stays high near 0 while the log of the Inverse Gaussian PDF diverges there.  Virtually all of the KL divergence is contributed by values in the interval [0, 0.05], which has a probability of 3.2% under the Gamma distribution.  The number of elements in a sample of $N = 1000$ Gamma variates which fall in this interval therefore has a Binomial(.032, $N$) distribution.  Its standard deviation equals $.032(1 - .032)/\sqrt{N}$ = 0.55%.  Thus, as a rough estimate, we can't expect your integral to have a relative accuracy much better than (3.2% - 2*0.55%) / 3.2% = give or take around 40%, because the number of times it samples this critical interval has this amount of error.  That accounts for the difference between your result and *Mathematica's*.  To get this error down to 1%--a mere two decimal places of precision--you would need to multiply your sample approximately by $(40/1)^2 = 1600$: that is, you would need a few million values.

Here is a histogram of *the natural logarithms* of 1000 independent estimates of the KL divergence.  Each estimate averages 1000 values randomly obtained from the Gamma distribution.  The correct value is shown as the dashed red line.

[image: Histogram]

```
Histogram[Log[Table[
 Mean[Log[PDF[red, #]/PDF[gray, #]] & /@ RandomReal[red, 1000]], {i,1,1000}]]]
```

Although *on the average* this Monte-Carlo method is unbiased, most of the time (87% in this simulation) the estimate is too low.  To make up for this, on occasion the overestimate can be gross: the largest of these estimates is 18.98. (The wide spread of values shows that the estimate of 1.286916 actually has *no* reliable decimal digits!)  Because of this huge skewness in the distribution, the situation is actually much worse than I previously estimated with the simple binomial thought experiment.  The average of these simulations (comprising 1000*1000 values total) is just 1.21, still about 25% less than the true value.

For computing the KL divergence in general, you need to use [adaptive quadrature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_quadrature) or exact methods.

Comment: Understood ! Thank you very much, again !
I have computed the KL divergence using the integrate() function of R and I have obtained the same result as yours.

Comment: @whuber wrote: "value of the KL divergence can be dominated by the integral in short intervals where the base PDF is nonzero and the other PDF is close to zero. A small sample can miss such intervals entirely and it can take a large sample to hit them enough times to obtain an accurate result."  Perhaps importance sampling could help ... a lot.