# Multidimensional KL loss

Tags: predictive-models, loss-functions, kullback-leibler

I read this [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/111445/148860) on **Kullback-Liebler Divergence**

Now i'm have a multidimensional distributions, like these:

for example I try to predict if a person in image is a male:

```
sample(img)  |     P_true     |     P_pred
             |                |            
             | n/a  |no | yes |  n/a |  no | yes
 A           |  0   | 1 |  0  |  0.2 | 0.6 | 0.2 
 B           |  0   | 0 |  1  |  0.1 | 0.0 | 0.9
 C           |  1   | 0 |  0  |  0.4 | 0.2 | 0.4
```

where **A,B,C** are my examples, **P_true** is the groundtruth (the correct labels) and **P_pred**, n/a is the label that i can't say if is a male or not.

The p_pred are estimated probability vector (obtained by a **softmax**).

what is the formula for compute **KL divergence with multidimensional probability vector**?

Comment: Its the same formula as in univar case, just replace simple integral with multivariate integral

Comment: thus i have a kl value for each element of the array, correct?

Comment: You must tell us much more, included how to read your arrays!  But Kullback-Leibler is a distance between distributions, not between vales.

Comment: i edit my question explaining how read the table

Comment: KLD is a divergence, not a distance.

Answer (score 0):

This is one-dimensional case when you have $P_\textrm{true}$ and $P_\textrm{pred}$ distributions [each value in your table *n/a, no, yes* are random variables with assigned probabilities to them].

Let's consider $P_\textrm{true}$ as $P$ and $P_\textrm{pred}$ as $Q$ then $D_{KL}(P\Vert Q)=\sum_ip_i \log \frac{p_i}{q_i}.$

There is a problem with computing $\log \frac{0}{0.2},$ so I'd recommend to replace all zeros with small values $\epsilon.$

Now you are able to calculate KL-divergence for each example A,B,C and even more :)

That's it.

Comment: An alternative could be found here:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/211175/kullback-leibler-divergence/248657#248657